# Entity Framework 4.0 changes in NopCommerce 1.90

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, nopcommerce

For learning EF, I was after a good example and I reached NopCommerce via google. I loved their implementation of EF and it's architecture in version 1.80.

I was very impressed with the Entity Framework Architecture in version 1.80. I liked the way of creating `AspNetObjectContextManager` and accessing the same `objectContext` for the request.

But now when I downloaded nopcommerce 1.90, I see all the classes `AspNetOCM`, `ObjectContextHelper`, `ObjectContextManager`, etc.. are removed and context is added to the Service classes (e.g. `CustomerService`).

Can I please know the reason behind it and if there are any shortcoming in the version 1.80's Entity Framework Architecture.

The reason I am concerned is that I don't want to learn the architecture with some shortcomings. I know NopCommerce development team have always maintained high level of quality in their coding, but I would love to know the reason behind removing the classes from version 1.90

Comment: So you should probably ask on their support or in their community forum. You are asking about implementation detail of third party product not about any real problem you have to deal with.

Comment: @Mrnka - yeah i did so too. But because stackoverflow community is vast and thought there might be someone who had same kind of query, who doesn't look at nopcommerce support forum, can provide me help

Answer (score 0):

I think this change relates to introduction of **IoC/DI** (inversion of control / dependency injection) pattern in 1.90.

This pattern enables you to set a service interface implementation (e.g. MyCustomerService for ICustomerService) in a config file, which contributes to loose coupling between client and service implementation(s).

However I've never tried NopCommerce 1.80, so can't tell what were the disadvantages of its architecture.